Http-only cookie can not be set when using Next.js Server component with server action
I have been using React but I am new to Next.js. Since React doc recommend Next.js as default, so I am now trying it.
I build a simple ASP.NET Core 8 Web API as backend.
I have implemented a simple login endpoint that will return a response with a JWT token, username and etc.
The login endpoint also generate a refresh token and set it as http-only cookie.
All of them working correctly in both Swagger and Postman.
After that, I built a simple Next.js app to test it.
However, although the login request will return a correct response to me, i.e. the JWT token, username and etc, I cannot see the refresh token in the Chrome developer tool's cookie panel.
I use useActionState to handle the login form, but it seems in React Canary now.
Please see my server action code here:
"use server"

const apiUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

export async function authenticate(prevState: string | undefined, formData: FormData) {

    try {

        const loginData = {
            username: formData.get('email'),
            password: formData.get('password'),
        };

        console.log(loginData);

        //Send request to backend
        const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/auth/login`, {
            method: 'POST',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(loginData),
        });

        //Check if it is a successful response
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorMessage = await response.text();
            // return errorMessage || "Failed to log in. Please try again.";
            return `Wrong username or password. Please try again. - ${errorMessage}`;
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
     
        return data;

    } catch (error) {
        //Other errors, such as internet error or backend error
        console.error('Login request failed:', error);
        return "Something wrong, please try again.";
    }
}

Then I tried the traditional way that I have been using in SPA, i.e. onSubmit event.
I moved and modified the server action out in to the login client component and its working correctly.
I can see the refresh token in the cookie panel now!
And then I realised it must be because of the different between server component and client component.
That is, if a server component is used to send a request, the back end cannot set a cookie for the browser.
Therefore, could you please kindly advise me how to set the refresh token as http-only cookie if I use server action in my case? Should I do it this way?
Or is this recommended to use Next.js is I already have a backend?
What is the best practice now if I would like to use Next.js as frontend and ASP.NET Core Web API as backend?
Thank you very much for your help.
